# mutate_each_ non-standard evaluation

Tags: r, dplyr

Really struggling with putting dplyr functions within my functions. I understand the `function_` suffix for the standard evaluation versions, but still having problems, and seemingly tried all combinations of `eval` `paste` and `lazy`.

Trying to divide multiple columns by the median of the control for a group. Example data includes an additional column in iris named 'Control', so each species has 40 'normal', and 10 'control'.

```
data(iris)
control <- rep(c(rep("normal", 40), rep("control", 10)), 3)
iris$Control <- control
```

Normal dplyr works fine:

```
out_df <- iris %>% 
    group_by(Species) %>% 
    mutate_each(funs(./median(.[Control == "control"])), 1:4)
```

Trying to wrap this up into a function:

```
norm_iris <- function(df, control_col, control_val, species, num_cols = 1:4){

out <- df %>%
    group_by_(species) %>% 
    mutate_each_(funs(./median(.[control_col == control])), num_cols)
    return(out)
}

norm_iris(iris, control_col = "Control", control_val = "control", species = "Species")
```

I get the error:

```
Error in UseMethod("as.lazy_dots") : 
no applicable method for 'as.lazy_dots' applied to an object of class "c('integer', 'numeric')"
```

Using `funs_` instead of `funs` I get `Error:...: need numeric data`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't already, it might help you to read the vignette on standard evaluation [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/nse.html), although it sounds like some of this may be changing soon.

Your function is missing the use of `interp` from package *lazyeval* in the `mutate_each_` line.  Because you are trying to use a variable name (the `Control` variable) in the `funs`, you need `funs_` in this situation along with `interp`.  Notice that this is a situation where you don't need `mutate_each_` at all.  You would need it if you were trying to use column names instead of column numbers when selecting the columns you want to mutate.

Here is what the line would look like in your function instead of what you have:

```
mutate_each(funs_(interp(~./median(.[x == control_val]), x = as.name(control_col))), 
                        num_cols)
```